# Javascript date shipping calculation

Tags: javascript, html, web

I would like to make script that calculates the date of the shipping.

Shipping is next date only in weekends it is in monday.

Can you please help me?

Example today is 16.12 and script should return shipping date 19.12 . If there is 17.12. script should return 19.12 too and same for 18.12.

Between business days the delivery is next day. So if we order 19.12. the script must return at 20.12.

Please help.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use JavaScript's getDay() after getting today's date. You would only then have to write code for fridays saturdays and possibly sundays

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_getday.asp

```
function getNextBusinessDay(dateIn) {

        var dayOfWeek = dateIn.getDay();
        var shippingDate = dateIn

        switch (dayOfWeek) {

            case 5:
                //friday add 3 days

                shippingDate = new Date(shippingDate.setDate(dateIn.getDate() + 3))

                break;

            case 6:
                //saturday add 2 days
                shippingDate = new Date(shippingDate.setDate(dateIn.getDate() + 2))

                break;

            default:
              //any other day so just add 1 day
                shippingDate = new Date(shippingDate.setDate(dateIn.getDate() + 1))

                break;

        }

        return shippingDate;
    }
```